# Mat Paginator errored out when using page event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on Paginator and need to call REST API, which has offset and limit as input parameter. For my work i have set the size of page as 10, and want that the next 10 records should get displayed on click of next page event. But every time the offset is getting assigned as `NaN`.

Require quick help.

**html code**

```
<mat-paginator [pageIndex]="pageIndex" [length]="length" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
      (page)="pageEvent = getPage($event)" [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
    </mat-paginator>
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class Exec implements OnInit{
  runData: Items;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Execution>;
  pageIndex: number = 1;
  pageSize: number= 10;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 15, 20];
  length: number;
  pageEvent: PageEvent;
  @Output() page = new EventEmitter<MatTableDataSource<Exec>>();
  constructor(private executionService: ExecutionService) { }  
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['abc','efg','efg'];  
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit() {     
    this.getData(this.pageIndex);
  }

  getPage(pageNo: number) {
    this.pageIndex = pageNo;
    this.getData(this.pageIndex);
  }

  getData(input: number){
    console.log('input is '+input +' offset is ==>'+(input - 1) * this.pageSize) // this is printed as "input is [object Object] offset is ==>NaN"
    let offset = (input - 1) * this.pageSize;
    this.exec.getDetails(offset,this.pageSize).subscribe(
      (response:Items) => {
        this.runData = response;
        console.log(this.runData);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Execution>(this.runData.items); 
        this.length =140;   // for testing. Total records will be used    
       // this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator;
       // this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;
      }
    );
    this.page.emit(this.dataSource); 
  }
}
```

Am i missing something in my approach?

Comment: Set the data source paginator to your paginator then set paginator length to data.length

Comment: @JohnPeters Added ```this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator;
        this.paginator.length=this.length;``` but still same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPage` function gets input as an event, not number. You need to modify `getPage` function like this:

```
getPage(event: any) {
   this.pageIndex = event.pageIndex;
   this.getData(this.pageIndex);
}
```

Comment: Its working now. Any idea how i can implement the first&last page functionality too? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @pulse if you want implement the first&last page, you only should use `showFirstLastButtons`, not `[showFirstLastButtons]="true"`